# Customised user page template name

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7. I want to override the page layout for all user profile pages, but I cannot figure out the specific name for page.tpl.php to override the default page.tpl.php. I tried page--profile.tpl.php, page--user, page-profile, page-user. Do I have to do something on the template.php file, to make it available like in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

page--user.tpl.php worked for me :)

Comment: i want to know which file is called before `page--user.tpl.php` in drupal

Comment: `page--user.tpl.php` is correct. Why isn't it `page--user-profile.tpl.php`? Where are these patterns documented?